# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very competitive election at the moment :). We have 3 vacancies and only 3 non-joke nominations :(   Step up people!

Comment: @DVK I believe there's only 2 vacancies (one additional mod plus one to replace Gilles).  The number of non-joke nominations has increased, as well :)

Answer (score 7):

Let me take this opportunity to announce that I am resigning from my moderator position on SF&F, effective when this election is completed. The Stack Exchange community teams knows about this, so two positions have been opened to bring the total number of moderators to 4.

You've probably noticed that I haven't been very active on the site lately. SF&F is largely a site for fans, and I am primarily a reader. Part of my [election platform](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-9998) was to make SF&F more attractive to readers, but let's face it: I have no idea how to do this.

I'll still be around, occasionally answering LOTR questions and defending story identification on Meta. Which is basically all I'm doing now... There are many other users who are far more active than me and who'd make good moderators. Let them have their time.

Comment: You'll be missed.

Comment: I'm confused, should I down-vote because I don't want you to resign or up-vote because of all the good work you have done?

Comment: "I have no idea how to do this." - Why don't you ramp up participation with **asking** exactly the type of synthesis/analysis questions you mentioned in your election platform (and heck, answering them too if no good answers surface, you are quite qualified to)? I would love to see such questions but would be deathly scared of posting them myself after seeing what happened when Tango tried a while back. So you can count at least on one VTRO/UV for sure.

Comment: @DVK [I do now and then](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles?tab=questions). I can't say I'm impressed by the answers I've gotten.